# Pagination not working

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

I have been using the same pagination query for the majority of the websites i have created. This time it is not working for some reason I have used the pagination trouble shooting links [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) but nothing seems to be working. I have attached my code below.

This time i am querying the post in a table so i think that must have something to do with it but i have queried it without a table and is still not working. Please see my code below.

New query

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
);
query_posts($args);
?>
```

The table with my table data from my custom meta fields.

```
<table>
    <thead >
        <tr>

            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php  while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metakey', true); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metakey', true); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metakey', true); ?></td>    
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metakey', true); ?></td>    

            </tr>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

My pagination links

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'prev_text'          => __(' Previous'),
    'next_text'          => __('Next '),
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

When I say its not working i mean that the pagination links are displayed the appropriate number of pages. but when i press on page two it isnt changing pages. the permalinks are right its says `domain/page/2` but the page is the same as page one. This is on a template page i created for `home-page.php` I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: describe what you mean by *not working*, what happens? what type of page is this on?

Comment: Hello @Milo Thank you for your response, when I say its not working i mean that the pagination links are displayed the appropriate number of pages. but when i press on page two it isnt changing pages. the permalinks are right its says domain/page/2 but the page is the same as page one. This is on a template page i created for home-page.php I appreciate the help.

Comment: Do **not** use `query_posts`, it breaks pagination and the main query

Comment: Also, please note, your comment should be an [edit] to your question. Many others skip and ignore comments, and they will skip and ignore your question as *doesn't work* also don't make much sense to them

Comment: @PieterGoosen thank you once again i will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already stated in comments, you should never use `query_posts`, only use `query_posts` if you are intended to break your page functionalities. Add `query_posts` to the very top of your **EVIL LIST**.

`query_posts` breaks the main query object, the very object that your pagination function relies on. Your pagination function relies on the `$max_num_pages` property from the main query. This is just **one** of the many things that `query_posts` break.

To solve your issue, make use of `WP_Query` as it seems that you are using a custom page template here. Just one note here, if `home-page.php` is a static front page, which I suspect from the template name, then

```
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
```

should be

```
'paged' => ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1),
```

as static front pages uses `page` and not `paged`

You can try something like this: (*Very important, this is untested and copied and pasted from OP, and **always** remember to reset postdata once you are done with your custom query*)

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<table>
    <thead >
        <tr>

            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>header</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php  while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
            <tr>

                <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metakey', true); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metakey', true); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metakey', true); ?></td>    
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metakey', true); ?></td>    

            </tr>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

You then just need to update your pagination function with the `$max_num_pages` property rom your custom query

```
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'prev_text'          => __(' Previous'),
    'next_text'          => __('Next '),
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

Comment: Amazing thank you i really appreciate it. I did not know of that before.

Comment: did this change recently? As of 2018 "paged" was working but it stopped working recently  (2020). Changed to "page" and is now working

Answer (score 1):

I was using a custom query and needed to paginate my query results. Since the original `paginate_links()` function is heavily tied to the global `$wp_query` and `$wp_rewrite` contexts, I have adapted it to be completely independent. usage:

```php
function myPaginateLinks( WP_Query $wp_query, $args = '' ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // Setting up default values based on the current URL.
    $pagenum_link = html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link() );
    $url_parts    = explode( '?', $pagenum_link );

    // Get max pages and current page out of the current query, if available.
    $total   = isset( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) ? $wp_query->max_num_pages : 1;
    $current = !empty($_GET['pg']) ? absint($_GET['pg']) : 1;

    // Append the format placeholder to the base URL.
    $pagenum_link = trailingslashit( $url_parts[0] ) . '%_%';

    // URL base depends on permalink settings.
    $format  = $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks() && ! strpos( $pagenum_link, 'index.php' ) ? 'index.php/' : '';
    $format .= '?pg=%#%';

    $defaults = array(
        'base'               => $pagenum_link, // http://example.com/all_posts.php%_% : %_% is replaced by format (below).
        'format'             => $format, // ?page=%#% : %#% is replaced by the page number.
        'total'              => $total,
        'current'            => $current,
        'aria_current'       => 'page',
        'show_all'           => false,
        'prev_next'          => true,
        'prev_text'          => __( '&laquo; Previous' ),
        'next_text'          => __( 'Next &raquo;' ),
        'end_size'           => 1,
        'mid_size'           => 2,
        'type'               => 'plain',
        'add_args'           => array(), // Array of query args to add.
        'add_fragment'       => '',
        'before_page_number' => '',
        'after_page_number'  => '',
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    if ( ! is_array( $args['add_args'] ) ) {
        $args['add_args'] = array();
    }

    // Merge additional query vars found in the original URL into 'add_args' array.
    if ( isset( $url_parts[1] ) ) {
        // Find the format argument.
        $format       = explode( '?', str_replace( '%_%', $args['format'], $args['base'] ) );
        $format_query = isset( $format[1] ) ? $format[1] : '';
        wp_parse_str( $format_query, $format_args );

        // Find the query args of the requested URL.
        wp_parse_str( $url_parts[1], $url_query_args );

        // Remove the format argument from the array of query arguments, to avoid overwriting custom format.
        foreach ( $format_args as $format_arg => $format_arg_value ) {
            unset( $url_query_args[ $format_arg ] );
        }

        $args['add_args'] = array_merge( $args['add_args'], urlencode_deep( $url_query_args ) );
    }

    // Who knows what else people pass in $args.
    $total = (int) $args['total'];
    if ( $total < 2 ) {
        return;
    }
    $current  = (int) $args['current'];
    $end_size = (int) $args['end_size']; // Out of bounds? Make it the default.
    if ( $end_size < 1 ) {
        $end_size = 1;
    }
    $mid_size = (int) $args['mid_size'];
    if ( $mid_size < 0 ) {
        $mid_size = 2;
    }

    $add_args   = $args['add_args'];
    $r          = '';
    $page_links = array();
    $dots       = false;

    if ( $args['prev_next'] && $current && 1 < $current ) :
        $link = str_replace( '%_%', 2 == $current ? '' : $args['format'], $args['base'] );
        $link = str_replace( '%#%', $current - 1, $link );
        if ( $add_args ) {
            $link = add_query_arg( $add_args, $link );
        }
        $link .= $args['add_fragment'];

        $page_links[] = sprintf(
            '<a class="prev page-numbers" href="%s">%s</a>',
            /**
             * Filters the paginated links for the given archive pages.
             *
             * @since 3.0.0
             *
             * @param string $link The paginated link URL.
             */
            esc_url( apply_filters( 'paginate_links', $link ) ),
            $args['prev_text']
        );
    endif;

    for ( $n = 1; $n <= $total; $n++ ) :
        if ( $n == $current ) :
            $page_links[] = sprintf(
                '<span aria-current="%s" class="page-numbers current">%s</span>',
                esc_attr( $args['aria_current'] ),
                $args['before_page_number'] . number_format_i18n( $n ) . $args['after_page_number']
            );

            $dots = true;
        else :
            if ( $args['show_all'] || ( $n <= $end_size || ( $current && $n >= $current - $mid_size && $n <= $current + $mid_size ) || $n > $total - $end_size ) ) :
                $link = str_replace( '%_%', 1 == $n ? '' : $args['format'], $args['base'] );
                $link = str_replace( '%#%', $n, $link );
                if ( $add_args ) {
                    $link = add_query_arg( $add_args, $link );
                }
                $link .= $args['add_fragment'];

                $page_links[] = sprintf(
                    '<a class="page-numbers" href="%s">%s</a>',
                    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/general-template.php */
                    esc_url( apply_filters( 'paginate_links', $link ) ),
                    $args['before_page_number'] . number_format_i18n( $n ) . $args['after_page_number']
                );

                $dots = true;
            elseif ( $dots && ! $args['show_all'] ) :
                $page_links[] = '<span class="page-numbers dots">' . __( '&hellip;' ) . '</span>';

                $dots = false;
            endif;
        endif;
    endfor;

    if ( $args['prev_next'] && $current && $current < $total ) :
        $link = str_replace( '%_%', $args['format'], $args['base'] );
        $link = str_replace( '%#%', $current + 1, $link );
        if ( $add_args ) {
            $link = add_query_arg( $add_args, $link );
        }
        $link .= $args['add_fragment'];

        $page_links[] = sprintf(
            '<a class="next page-numbers" href="%s">%s</a>',
            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/general-template.php */
            esc_url( apply_filters( 'paginate_links', $link ) ),
            $args['next_text']
        );
    endif;

    switch ( $args['type'] ) {
        case 'array':
            return $page_links;

        case 'list':
            $r .= "<ul class='page-numbers'>\n\t<li>";
            $r .= implode( "</li>\n\t<li>", $page_links );
            $r .= "</li>\n</ul>\n";
            break;

        default:
            $r = implode( "\n", $page_links );
            break;
    }

    /**
     * Filters the HTML output of paginated links for archives.
     *
     * @since 5.7.0
     *
     * @param string $r    HTML output.
     * @param array  $args An array of arguments. See paginate_links()
     *                     for information on accepted arguments.
     */
    $r = apply_filters( 'paginate_links_output', $r, $args );

    return $r;
}
```

Usage example:

```
$myQuery = new WP_Query();

$cars = $myQuery->query([
    'post_type' => 'cars',
    'paged' => !empty($_GET['pg']) ? absint($_GET['pg']) : 1,
]);

foreach ($cars as $car) {
    echo $car->post_title;
}

echo myPaginateLinks($myQuery);
```

Which produces the exact same result as paginate_links, but without any ties to the global query or rewrite rules:

[image: wordpress pagination custom query custom post type cpt]

Notice that I'm using `$_GET['pg']` instead of `?paged` for the pagination, as I didn't want any "rewrite magic" getting into the way of the pagination.